# AngularJS routing error inside a controller

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-routing

I have the following AngularJS routing setup.

## app.js

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
  //some code
  .state('app.edit', {
    url: '/edit/:recipeId',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/recipes/edit.html',
        controller: 'editRecipeCtrl'
      }
    }
  //some code
});
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/home');
```

## view

```
<a ng-click="editDemo()" href='#'>Edit</a>
```

The problem is when I click the link, it does not go to the edit page. (following are the observations)

- No error in the console
- I can see the url is changing in the address bar, but it quickly
  fall-back to the home page
- If I type `http://localhost/#/app/edit/1` in the address bar , it works
- it calls the `editDemo()` method.

## controller.js

```
$scope.editDemo = function(){
    // options I tried
     
    // $location.path( '/edit/1' );
    // $location.path( '#/app/edit/1');  
    // $location.path( 'edit/1');  
    // $location.url( '/edit/1' );
    // $location.url( '#/app/edit/1' ); 
    // $location.url( 'edit/1');
    // location.href = '/#/app/edit/1';
}
```

Comment: `$location.path( '/edit/1' );` should be correct, try passing `$event` to `ng-click` callback and call `$event.preventDefault()`

Comment: @Rasalom, thanks for the quick answer, I updated the link to div `<div ng-click="editDemo()">Edit</div>` and code to `$location.path( '/edit/1' );`, but still doesnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer (to prevent pitfalls) to use the $state service

```
$scope.editDemo = function(id) {
    $state.go('app.edit', {recipeId: id});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have at least 2 ways here:

1) remove `href` from `<a>` tag: `<a ng-click="editDemo()">Edit</a>`
and in editDemo:

```
$scope.editDemo = function(){
   $location.path( '/edit/1' );
}
```

2) work with click event in editDemo:

```
<a ng-click="editDemo($event)" href='#'>Edit</a>

$scope.editDemo = function($event){
     $event.preventDefault();
     $location.path( '/edit/1' );
}
```

Comment: thanks @Rasalom, I changed the code to Ben's way and its working now. and I believe its more like `angular`. But thanks again :)